# SSIS ingestion from SharePoint with oData broken - Internal Server Error 500

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, odata

I have SSIS packages that use the oData data source to pull data directly from SharePoint lists and libraries into SQL Server.  The packages worked before I left my civilian job on military leave, and now they don't.

The only thing that's different is that the following list of patches have been installed on the dev SharePoint server: KB4011599, KB4011579, KB4011653, and KB4011170.

The team that controls our Production environment just told us that ONLY the first patch was applied....and our SSIS packages in production still work.

I have no idea where even to start looking at this.  I've looked at the SharePoint logs, and they're also no help...all I see is the Internal Server Error (500).

I don't want to be spoon-fed, but I would greatly appreciate some help in pointing me in the right direction.